# How to query and mutate "many-to-many" fields in my table?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, apollo, typeorm

I am new to nestjs. I have two entities:

```
@Entity({ name: "Books" })
@ObjectType()
export class Book {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field()
  id: number;
  @Column()
  @Field()
  title: string;
  @ManyToMany(() => Author, (author: Author) => author.books)
  @Field(() => [Author])
  authors: Author[];
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: "Authors" })
@ObjectType()
export class Author {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @Field()
  id: Number;
  @Column()
  @Field()
  firstName: string;
  @Column()
  @Field()
  lastName: string;
  @ManyToMany(() => Book, (book: Book) => book.authors)
  @JoinTable()
  @Field(() => [Book])
  books: Book[];
}
```

This automatically gives me a third empty table "authors_books_books". How to establish a relationship between authors and books? Not only between the abstract author and the abstract book, but specify that this author with the id: x wrote the book with the id: y? In other words: how can I fill "authors_books_books" table with data?

Answer (score 0):

Typeorm does technically have [built-in ways to handle this...](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-many-relations.md#saving-many-to-many-relations)

That said, I prefer the quick way that doesn't require having the objects:

```
await this.manager.query(
    'INSERT INTO authors_books_books ("authorId", "bookId") VALUES ($1, $2)',
    [authorId, bookId],
);
```